# OpenCV 2.4.9 VideoWriter is not working on target

Tags: opencv

I have installed opencv 2.4.9 using yocto project.

```cpp
VideoWriter video("out.avi",CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'),30, 
  Size(frame_width,frame_height));
```

is not creating the out.avi file.

This is the code:

```cpp
int main()
{
  cv::VideoCapture capture(0);

  int frame_width = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
  int frame_height = capture.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);

  VideoWriter video("out.avi", CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G'), 30, 
    Size(frame_width,frame_height));

  if (!capture.isOpened())
  {
    printf("Error in open\n");
  }

  cv::Mat frame;

  while(1)
  {
    if (!capture.read(frame))
    {
      printf("Error in capture\n");
    }
    video.write(frame);

    cv::waitKey(30);
  }
}
```

But the same code is working on x86 linux.

Comment: If the exact same code works on Linux, then it's probably a problem of codecs available. 
You can try to replace `CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G')` by -1 so that you will be asked to use one codec among the ones available on your machine.

Comment: I would also advise you to add `video.release();` after your loop ends. Sometimes when the VideoWriter is poorly released, the video will be created but you won't be able to read it with VLC or any other media player.

Comment: @AxelB. It's likely these are the issue, you should just write them up into an answer.

Comment: if the codec is not supported, a 1kB sized file is created (especially if opencv_ffmpeg*.dll is missing). How are you starting your application? Where's your working directory? Can you try std::ofstream test(out.test.txt); and check whether this file is created in the folder?

Comment: @Micka is right, the codec can't explain it all.

Moreover, there is another problem in your code: you are using your webcam as the VideoCapture device (theoretically, infinite amount of frames) and you are running an infinite loop, without any way to break from it. There is no way you could escape your program properly and thus ensure your video to be correctly built.

Answer (score 2):

If the code works on Linux, the error probably comes from the fact that you don't have the MJPG codec available on your Windows machine.
One simple way to test it would be to replace `CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G')` by -1 so that your program will ask you to choose the codec among a list.

In addition to this, I would advise you to add `video.release();` after your while-loop. Sometimes when the VideoWriter instance is poorly released, the video will be created but you won't be able to read it with VLC or any other media player.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I changed CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G') by -1 and tried. But file itself not creating.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for replying. I changed CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G') by -1 and tried. But file itself not creating.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled with the cap.cpp and cap_gstreamer.cpp from opencv 2.4.10 package.
And I compiled with proper library and include like,

g++ capture.cpp cap.cpp cap_gstreamer.cpp -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lfontconfig -lfreetype -lgthread-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lgstbase-1.0 -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lgstvideo-1.0 -lgstbase-1.0 -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lgstapp-1.0 -lgstbase-1.0 -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lgstriff-1.0 -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lgstpbutils-1.0 -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lv4l1 -lv4l2 -lavcodec -lavformat -lavutil -lswscale -lbz2 -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_flann

Then this capturing is working for me. Thank you.